# tb_show is not defined in advance custom field

Tags: errors

I am using the plugin: Advanced Custom Fields. For several more images, I used it to add images using the image input field.

Now, when I edit a post, I can't edit/add new image into the image field using the plugin. Using Firebug, it shows a `js` error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: tb_show is not defined

But the same fields work, when I add a new image using those fields.

Comment: Did you try to add `wp_enqueue_script( 'thickbox' )` to your `functions.php`?

Comment: tried. But it's not working. :( Posted the same question now to the [WP.org support thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/on-edit-post-ajax-is-not-working?replies=0#post-4338746).

Comment: @MayeenulIslam Please clean up your accounts.

Comment: disable other plugins and switch to default theme, check if the issue still exists.

Comment: @toscho, Nishi is a colleague of mine. Not my account. :) And we both are in the same project with the same problem. :(

Answer (score 5):

Did you also add `wp_enqueue_script('media-upload')` in functions.php ?

I tried this and it's working:

```
function load_admin_things() {
    wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
    wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_admin_things' );
```